# Updating two checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have two checkboxGroupInputs and I would like the two update in tandem. In other words, updating one should update the other, but then updating the other should keep what the first selected and then just continue updating the selections. Bu updating, I mean providing the choice values.

The toy example provides an illustrative case, however, here we can clearly see that when I am done updating the first, and the continuous updating the second box, the first box resets. I want to avoid this resetting. Also, it should not matter if the user starts selecting in the first or the second box. The procedure should be invariant to that.

I have tried two approaches, one using the updateCheckboxGroupInput function, and using reactives (commeted out).

Any suggestions are welcomed:

```
library(shiny)
# Shiny server object
# Define UI for app 
ui <- fluidPage(


  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    uiOutput("boxes"),


    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Histogram ----
      textOutput(outputId = "TestText")

    )
  )

)

age.values <- 1:10

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # define reactive
  age <- reactiveVal()
  age(age.values)

  valuesMax <- reactiveVal()  
  valuesMin <- reactiveVal()

  valuesMin(age.values)
  valuesMax(age.values)


  # v <- age[which(!age %in% valuesMin[1:2])]
  # v

  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----


  # update reactives
  # if valuesMax updates then update valuesMin
  # observeEvent(input$go, {
  #   
  #   # define valuesMin whatever values is remaining
  #   v <- age()[which(!age() %in% input$age.bins.max)]
  #   
  #   valuesMin(v)
  #   
  # })
  # 
  # observeEvent(input$go, {
  #   
  #   # define valuesMin whatever values is remaining
  #   w <- age()[which(!age() %in% input$age.bins.min)]
  #   
  #   valuesMax(w)
  #   
  # })    



  ##### 0. Pre-processing ####
  output$boxes <- renderUI({

    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "age.bins.min", 
                         "Select mono decreasing age groups",
                         choiceNames = paste("age group", age()),
                         choiceValues = age(),
                         inline = T,
                         selected=character(0)),


      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "age.bins.max", 
                         "Select mono increasing age groups ",
                         choiceNames = paste("age group", age()),
                         choiceValues =  age(),
                         inline = T,
                         selected=character(0)),
      actionButton(inputId = "go", 
                   label = "Update"))

  })

  observe({
    x <- input$age.bins.min

    # Can use character(0) to remove all choices
    if (is.null(x))
      x <- character(0)

    w <- age()[which(!age() %in% x)]


    # Can also set the label and select items
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "age.bins.max",
                             label = paste("age group", w),
                             choices = w,
                             selected = character(0))

  })


  observe({
    y <- input$age.bins.max

    # Can use character(0) to remove all choices
    if (is.null(y))
      y <- character(0)

    v <- age()[which(!age() %in% y)]


    # Can also set the label and select items
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "age.bins.min",
                             label = paste("age group", v),
                             choices = v,
                             selected = character(0))

  })



  # output$TestText <- renderText({
  #   max <- paste("valuesMax", valuesMax())
  #   min <- paste("valuesMin", valuesMin())
  #   
  #   print(max)
  #   #print(min)
  #   
  #   
  # })
  # 




}


# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Why not just fill `selected` argument with whatever is currently selected?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @Ryan Morton. Yes, you are correct! I was thinking about the selected argument in the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but does the following solve your problem?

For dealing with min and max range values I prefer the inputSlider but, then again, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

**Update**
There seemed to be a problem with observeEvent not updating when input values changed from an integer value to NULL. I now rewrote the two `observeEvent` statements as one `observe` and it works now also when deselecting values.

```
library(shiny)
# Shiny server object
# Define UI for app 
ui <- fluidPage(


  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    uiOutput("boxes"),


    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Histogram ----
      textOutput(outputId = "TestText")

    )
  )

)

age.values <- 1:10

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----

  output$boxes <- renderUI({

    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "age.bins.min", 
                         "Select mono decreasing age groups",
                         choiceNames = paste("age group", age()),
                         choiceValues = age(),
                         inline = T,
                         selected = character(0)),


      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "age.bins.max", 
                         "Select mono increasing age groups ",
                         choiceNames = paste("age group", age()),
                         choiceValues = age(),
                         inline = T,
                         selected = character(0)),

      actionButton(inputId = "go", 
                   label = "Update"))

  })

  # define reactive
  age <- reactiveVal(age.values)

     observe({

    x <- input$age.bins.min
    if (is.null(x))
      x <- character(0)

    y <- input$age.bins.max
    if (is.null(y))
      y <- character(0)

    w1 <- age()[!(age() %in% y)]

    w1n <- if(length(w1)==0) character(0)
              else paste("age group", w1)

    w2 <- age()[!(age() %in% x)]

    w2n <- if(length(w2)==0) character(0)
               else paste("age group", w2)

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "age.bins.min",
                             choiceNames = w1n,
                             choiceValues = w1,
                             selected = x)

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "age.bins.max",
                             choiceNames = w2n,
                             choiceValues = w2,
                             selected = y)



  })



}


# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: How do we make sure that one deselecting the final group that that group re-appears in the other tile of boxes? E.g. select 1 and 2 in first tile of boxes, then deselect those boxes in the first tile. But only box 2 re-appears in the second tile of boxes.

Comment: See my updated answer. Apparently, `observeEvent` has some problems when the input value changes from some integer to NULL. I  rewrote the `observeEvent` as `observe` and it should now work as expected.

Comment: @TimTearFan, so a new funny thing arises when you select all groups. The app crashes with "Warning: Error in normalizeChoicesArgs: `choiceNames` and `choiceValues` must have the same length". How would you control this situation? Would we need to add another if-statment?
"